# Read values from a webview in android

Tags: android, webview

I have a webview in a alertbox, in this webview I have a `<textarea>`

Anyone have an idea how to get the texts typed in this field and be used in the android app. as normal `Edittext` fields

Happy Coding..!

Answer (score 0):

Its not possible as you are saying. An alternative can be helpful. You should add an interface to your WebView which contains a method which can get value from web page. You have create and to call a javascript function which can pass the value of your textarea to your interface function by using that Interface. I hope you understand.
For example: Add an interface to your Webview like:

```
mainView.addJavascriptInterface(MyOwnCreatedClassName, "AndroidInterface");
```

Here MyOwnCreatedClassName is the name of the class which will contain that method and AndroidInterface is the name that the Javascript will use to call that method.

for complete example follow:
[Using webView.AddJavascriptInterface with MonoDroid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6505878/using-webview-addjavascriptinterface-with-monodroid)